# Buttons in bootstrap navbar are overwriting and not collapsing and/or decreasing in size on reducing screen size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am very new to bootstrap. I somehow managed to put up a navbar with few buttons in it. On reducing the screen size the buttons text gets overwritten and navbar flows way out of the screen. This happens on reducing the screen size to 1000 pixels. I do not want my navbar to collapse at this size. Any way where I can prevent the buttons text from getting overwritten AND prevent my navbar to flow out of the screen?
Link of the page: https://piyush16108.github.io/lets_try/
To see the issue, reduce the screen width to 1000px or so

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post to add some code. Remove the Bootstrap version tag that doesn't apply to your situation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

please provide the code what you did that way others can see what you did wrong and it will be easier to solve your problem. Don't worry I did solve your problem by inspecting it. just change the class in nav element to

```
navbar-expand-lg
```

instead of

```
navbar-expand-md
```